# Signal.alarm not raising while other function is executing

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, signals

I have a Lambda function which does some querying to a database using the `teradatasql` library. I have a 15 minute timeout on my Lambda, but I want to make sure to throw an exception before hitting that timeout to let users know their query timed out. Here's the basic idea:

```
import signal
import teradatasql

class TimeoutException(Exception):
    pass


def timeout_handler(signal, frame):
    raise TimeoutException("Query failed to execute in time")

def query_database(statements):
    connect = teradatasql.connect(**kwargs)
    cursor = connect.cursor()
    for statement in statements:
        cursor.execute(statement)
    return cursor.fetchall()

def handler(event, context):
    try:
        # When an ALARM is raised, call the handler
        signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, timeout_handler)
        # Raise an ALARM if we hit are within 15 seconds of the timeout
        signal.alarm((context.get_remaining_time_in_millis() // 1000) - 15)
        # Run queries
        query_database(event['statements'])
    except TimeoutError:
        raise Exception("Statements were not processed in time")
```

I am seeing some strange behavior.

- Currently, the alarm does not get raised and the Lambda simply fails with the RuntimeError for timing out at the threshold.
- If I remove the `signal.signal` call to assign a handler to the alarm, the alarm raises when expected but no handler around it is useless.
- If I replace `query_database` body with a `time.sleep(1000)` then the alarm will raise as expected.

Is there something to do with the library `teradatasql` and how it uses threads? Should I place the `signal.signal` call somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

The teradatasql driver offers a request timeout feature.

On each pass through the for-loop, calculate the time your Lambda has remaining, and specify the remaining amount of time as the request timeout as your Lambda executes each SQL request.

Prepend the escape function `{fn teradata_request_timeout(Seconds)}` to each SQL request, and specify the desired request timeout as the Seconds argument to the escape function.

If the SQL request execution time exceeds the request timeout, then the teradatasql driver will abort the SQL request and raise an error to your Lambda.